# Rigidly fixing a model to the world

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are clear instructions here for rigidly fixing a model to the world: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf#RigidlyFixingAModeltotheWorld Indeed, this works when you use a link called "world". It does not work if you use another name. Is there specific hardcoded behavior for "world" for some reason?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24075/rigidly-fixing-a-model-to-the-world/) by [mogumbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6355/mogumbo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, the keyword `world` is used to fix a joint to the world. If you name a model / link `world`, that should cause problems.

[This tutorial](http://sdformat.org/tutorials?tut=pose_frame_semantics&cat=specification&#specifying-parent-and-child-link-names-for-joints-in-sdf-1-4) mentions the special treatment for the `world` keyword. The reason why that word is reserved is that we need some way to identify a fixed inertial frame.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6355/mogumbo/) on 2019-11-05**:
Thanks. Do you know of any documentation that explicitly states this name is reserved and explains the reasons why?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-11-05**:
I added a bit more context to the answer. I hope that answers your question?

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6355/mogumbo/) on 2019-11-05**:
That's much more clear. Thank you.